# error in distinctUntilChaned if no comparer function provided

Tags: angular, rxjs

given this code:

```
/**
 * Create a stream from an array of car objects.
 */
from([
  { name: 'Porsche', model: '911' },
  { name: 'Porsche', model: '911' },
  { name: 'Ferrari', model: 'F40' }
]).pipe(
  /**
   * Use keySelectorFn to return car names for use in comparison
   */
  distinctUntilChanged(null, (car) => car.name)
)
.subscribe(console.log);

// console output: 
// {name: "Porsche", model: "911"}
// {name: "Ferrari", model: "F40"}
```

TS complains that `Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previous: unknown, current: unknown) => boolean'`.

If I change it to `undefined`, the same error.

Even in the rxjs docs is `undefined` used:

```
// A stream of updates to a given account
const accountUpdates$ = of(
  { updatedBy: 'blesh', data: [] },
  { updatedBy: 'blesh', data: [] },
  { updatedBy: 'ncjamieson', data: [] },
  { updatedBy: 'ncjamieson', data: [] },
  { updatedBy: 'blesh', data: [] }
);
 
// We only want the events where it changed hands
const changedHands$ = accountUpdates$.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(undefined, update => update.updatedBy)
);
```

In this code example I also get the same error.

So, the question is: how to set the comparer function to null/undefined without error?

My TS version is 4.9.3. RxJs version is 7.5.0.

Comment: I have added it to the question at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it may be a quirk in the typing for `distinctUntilChanged`.  The error would probably go away if you disabled `strictNullChecks` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

However, you can just use [`distinctUntilKeyChanged`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/distinctUntilKeyChanged) instead:

```js
distinctUntilKeyChanged('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
distinctUntilChanged((prev:any,curr:any) => prev.name === curr.name)
```